# run server and clients on one machine (netbeans 8.1)

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I have a problem to run a server and clients in one (mac) machine. I can run the server but when I run the client it give me an error `java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)`
as far as I know that there is somthing call ssh that need to be used but I don't know how to use it to do solve this. 
Thanks

```
public class WRRCourseWork {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DatagramSocket IN_socket = new DatagramSocket(3000);
        DatagramSocket OUT_socket = new DatagramSocket(5000);
        IN_socket.setSoTimeout(0);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        while (true) {
            //recive the message 

            IN_socket.receive(packet);
            String message = new String(buffer);
            System.out.println("Got message: " + message.trim());

            // send the message 
            String host = "";
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            DatagramPacket OUT_Packet = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.getBytes().length, addr, 5000);
            OUT_socket.send(OUT_Packet);
            System.out.println("Sending Message: "+ message.trim());
        } 

    } catch (Exception error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

... client

```
    public class Messages {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("hiiiiiii");
        //String host = "localhost";
        try {
            while (true) {
                InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                String message = "Hello World";
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.getBytes().length, addr, 4000);
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(4000);
                socket.send(packet);
                //socket.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception error) {
            // catch all errors
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server is listening on port 3000 so change your client to also use port 3000 and to only specify port 3000 once, in the packet definition not in the socket.

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Messages {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println("hiiiiiii");
    //String host = "localhost";
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        while (true) {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String message = "Hello World";
          DatagramPacket packet = 
                  new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), 
                          message.getBytes().length, addr, 3000);
          socket = new DatagramSocket();
          socket.send(packet);
          socket.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception error) {
        // catch all errors
        error.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

The results on the server should then be:

```
Got message: Hello World
Sending Message: Hello World
Got message: Hello World
Sending Message: Hello World
Got message: Hello World
Sending Message: Hello World
. . .
```